# How to fix 'Methode called on null in a streambuilder'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch data from firestore but I keep getting methode called on null error
I want it to keep showing circular progress indicator in case of an error or slow connection

```
class FirstTabPage extends StatelessWidget {

 final CustomCard customCard = CustomCard();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return 
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: StreamBuilder(

          stream: Firestore.instance.document('data/Sqprices').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){ 

             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.black,),);
             } else { 

              return ListView(
               children: <Widget>[
               CustomCard(
                 image: Image.asset('images/elag.png',width: 40,height: 40,),
                 currencyName: 'EUR',
                 buyPrice: '${snapshot.data['price1']}',
                 sellPrice: '${snapshot.data['price2']}',
                 ),
                 CustomCard(
                 image: Image.asset('images/ulag.png',width: 40,height: 40,),
                 currencyName: 'USD',
                 buyPrice: '${snapshot.data['price3']}',
                 sellPrice: '${snapshot.data['price4']}',
                 ),
                 CustomCard(
                 image: Image.asset('images/klag.png',width: 40,height: 40,),
                 currencyName: 'GBP',
                 buyPrice: '${snapshot.data['price5']}',
                 sellPrice: '${snapshot.data['price6']}',
                 ),
               ],
              );
          }
          }

    ),
      );

  }


}
```

When there is internet acces the progress indicator shows for 2 seconds and then the data get displayed , but in slow internet acces it crashes saying the
the methode [] was called on null

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){
 ...... 
 ..... 
 .... 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work , same thing , It says of type AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> when I hover above it

Answer (score 0):

You have checked for `.hasData` which ensures that data should be available in the Stream. However, the data in the Stream can also be null data. So, you should check if data equals null:

```
     child: StreamBuilder(

          stream: Firestore.instance.document('data/Sqprices').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){ 

             return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.black,),);
             } 
if(snapshot.data == null) return Center(child: Text("No data"));

else { 

              return ListView(
```

Comment: Even after checking for data non null , it throws the same error